# Strange behaviour with vim-lsp+clangd+asyncomplete-lsp

Tags: vimrc, autocompletion, lsp

here is my .vimrc:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'prabirshrestha/vim-lsp'
Plug 'mattn/vim-lsp-settings'
Plug 'prabirshrestha/asyncomplete.vim'
Plug 'prabirshrestha/asyncomplete-lsp.vim'
Plug 'piec/vim-lsp-clangd'
call plug#end()

:set tabstop=4 smarttab
:set shiftwidth=2
:set autoindent
:set smartindent

let g:lsp_document_highlight_enabled = 1

inoremap <expr> <Tab>   pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<Tab>"
inoremap <expr> <S-Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<C-n>"
inoremap <expr> <cr>    pumvisible() ? asyncomplete#close_popup() : "\<cr>"
```

Very simple but when I want to use antocompletion, I don't get the expected behavior.

Lets say:

- I start to write `temp`,
- The keyword `template` is proposed in the popup (clangd is well recognized here, I get C++ completion not general one like on fresh Vim install),
- But if I do <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> I get something like: `temptemplate`

So the few characters I wrote before using autocompletion remains.

Comment: Welcome to Vim! Your problem look like a bug of `asyncomplete` I believe the best is to submit it as a bug to the project :-/